# Where does ubuntu 14.04 drop core files?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have enabled a unlimited core file size using ulimit:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
...
```

I believe I have triggered a core dump but I can't locate the core file in my home, var/... etc...

Do you know where Ubuntu configures the core dump location?

Comment: @djf the OP didn't specify what program was causing core dumps. It may not be programmers code. It may be Unity for all we know.

Comment: How is this a SuperUser question? This is about running a debugger which only programmers use. This should be migrated back to SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a more Linux kernel thing than a specific Ubuntu thing.  Check out

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Check out the [core file man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)

Comment: That does not tell you where it puts the file.  The question named Ubuntu 14.04.  It is not clear at all by following the command in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` where one would find the file.

Comment: For me, that core_pattern kernel pseudofile references a program called 'apport'... which has no man page nor much helpful output. So still searching for my dumped cores. :(

Comment: apport is the standard linux desktop core handler it reports back to your distro usually.

Comment: How to open this folder? `cd /usr/share/apport/apport` don't work.

Answer (score 31):

By default, the Ubuntu kernel is configured to use apport to log coredumps. You can override this by overwriting `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, check the "Naming of core dump files" section in `man core` for details. For example:

`echo '/tmp/core.%e.%p.%t' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Apport writes core dumps to `/var/crash/_path_to_program.userid.crash`, BUT it will only do so for applications installed from the main ubuntu apt repositories.

More info on apport: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

Comment: To write core dumps for non-package programs as well, create a file named *~/.config/apport/settings* with the following contents:

*[main]*
*unpackaged=true*

Comment: Modifying the */proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern* does not work for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, my core dump was located at:

`/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.application-name.0.24d47e89526c4c7e90953998d2c33d1e.19672.1516049424000000000000`

So, to run it in `gdb`, you can run:

`apt install gdb
gdb /path/to/your/binary/application-name /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.application-name.0.24d47e89526c4c7e90953998d2c33d1e.19672.1516049424000000000000`