# Unable to enable core dumps (ubuntu/ARM)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, ulimit, segmentation-fault

I'm struggling to enable core dumps in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (ARM) running on an nVidia Jetson TX1 SBC. I've done all of the usual stuff, including suggestions from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/849099/where-does-ubuntu-14-04-drop-core-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-when-a-process-gets-a-segmentation-fault). There is plenty of space on the root filesystem, which is writable. The application does *not* have the suid bit set. I have also disabled ubuntu's "apport" service. Here's what I've set:

/etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*               soft    core            unlimited
*               hard    core            unlimited
```

Kernel core settings:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
core
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid
1
```

Output of ulimit:

```
$ ulimit -c
unlimited
```

And after starting my process:

```
$ egrep "Units|core" /proc/$(pgrep my_app_name)/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
```

But no cores are generated when the application segfaults, aborts, or has a floating point exception. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see that could cause that would be that the current working directory of the application is not writable to the running user.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely not the case, running out of my home directory where I've been doing some development. I'm stumped.